# How to add a cron trigger with or condition?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

My condition is like that,
 i want a trigger to be fired every month on the date say 30, but the month February dosn't have this particular date ,so during execution will the quartz through a exception or it will execute that trigger on the day 28 for February.if it throws a exception then what will be the solution.

thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
.startNow()
.withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 15 L * ?")) 
.build();

// fire on the last day of every month at 15:00

Reffer this link

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/MonthlyTrigger